# Partner Business Org Licenses

Tags: appexchange

For new ISV partners that are creating a free AppExchange listing, are the Partner Business Orgs eligible for the 2 free EE licenses?

Comment: IIRC yes, you get two free licenses when you become an ISV - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/isv1_3_quickstart.htm - If you are an ISV and submit a package you need it to manage the product....